# Как сделать прекращение движения персонажа при отпускании кнопки?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я создал кнопку в юнити 2д, и в `OnClick` написал метод `rmove` со следующим содержанием

```
public void rmove()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(2.0f, 0.0f);
    }
```

По моей задумке при нажатии на кнопку персонаж должен идти вперед, а при отпускании - остановиться. Работает наполовину так как при нажатии он идет, но при отпускании не останавливается.

Comment: ну вы приравниваете значение скорости, а не увеличиваете/уменьшаете её значение. Конечно он после первого нажатия просто станет идти, и больше ничего меняться не будет. К сожалению, я не могу вам подсказать как решить проблему, я не Untity-разрабочик, но я постарался объяснить, в чём проблема

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь твоя задумка не умеет ходить сквозь бетонные стены реальности.

Кнопка выполняет функцию, как ни странно, кнопки и реагирует только на единственное событие клика. Что-то обрабатывающее два состояния вкл/выкл это toggle. Тебе же нужен toggle меняющий состояния зажатием, что чем-то напоминает кнопку.

Все события UI в Unity обрабатываются через интерфейсы:

- [IPointerDownHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) нажатие на объект
- [IPointerUpHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerUpHandler.html) разжатие объекта (если он был ранее нажат)

Таких интерфейсов много, на все случаи. Но на объекте должен быть `Image` или любой другой наследник `Graphic`, с полем `Raycast Target ☑`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void rmove(float _coif)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(2.0f*coif, 0.0f);
    }
```

Делаем вот так и при ЗАЖАТИИ (down) копки вызываем метод и передаем туда (в _coif) 1, а при ОТПУСКАНИИ (up) кнопку передаём туда 0. Таким образом когда вы отпустите кнопку, то скорость сделается на 0 и перс остановиться.

И это лучше всего сделать в EventTrigger (компонент, который лучше всего наложить на Image), кнопками не советую пользоваться :)